# how to make the positive value and negative value in same direction in ggplot2 bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

```
group = letters[1:10]
response = sample(-5:5, size=10, replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(group,
           response)
```

I want to make the figure like this figure [wanted results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5ojO.png) to show the value of my research, but my data has both negative and positive values. I wonder how to change the y-axis to make them in the same direction. I tried to set the y-axis limits by `scale_y_continuous()` but it didn't work [See My results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjaS7.png). Thanks a lot for any possible solutions.

Here's my plotting code

```
ggplot(df) +
 aes(x = group, y = response, fill = response) +
 geom_col() +
 scale_fill_distiller(palette = "PiYG", 
 direction = 1) +
 theme_minimal() +
 theme(legend.position = "bottom")+coord_polar()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about, instead of "response", mapping abs(response) to your y axis? I am assuming you want te colors to still reflect the original values, so you could keep fill mapped to "response".

Like so:

```
ggplot(df) +
 aes(x = group, y = abs(response), fill = response) +
 geom_col() +
 scale_fill_distiller(palette = "PiYG", 
 direction = 1) +
 theme_minimal() +
 theme(legend.position = "bottom")+coord_polar()
```

Comment: Thanks @matfra a lot! I think it solved my problem and the figure looked much better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `abs(response)` to generate absolute values for the y-axis. According to the desirable output you shared, you could also try reordering the groups using `reorder(strwrap(x,10),y)` to have ordered groups from that with the smallest response value to the largest. Additionally, I think `theme_gray()` with `theme(legend.position = "right")` completes the plot well.
I have also added the following lines to properly label your axes:

```
Response = abs(response)#y-axis
Group = reorder(strwrap(group, 10), 
                Response)#x-axis
```

BTW, I'm new here, so please forgive me if my write-up and code is not well embedded :)

Here's my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
group = letters[1:10]
response = sample(-5:5, size=10, replace=TRUE)

df <- data.frame(group, response)

Response = abs(response)
Group = reorder(strwrap(group, 10), 
                Response)
ggplot(df) +
  aes(Group, Response, fill = response) +
  geom_col()+
  theme_gray()+
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "PiYG", 
                      direction = 1) +
  theme(legend.position = "right")+
  coord_polar()
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sulman for your nice solution and also for aesthetic improvement. I think it improved my figure a lot. I am also new to R so really appreciate you being willing to share.